# GridLayout attach an ImageView dynamically

Tags: android, android-gridlayout

I am trying to create a 15(width)x20(height) "graph-paper" like view using `GridLayout` as defined as such on `xml`.

```
<GridLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:columnCount="15"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:rowCount="20"
                    android:layout_margin="2dp"
                    android:id="@+id/gridLayout_mazeLayout">
                    <View
                        android:layout_width="15dp"
                        android:layout_height="15dp"
                        android:layout_row="0"
                        android:layout_column="0"
                        android:background="#51ffff"
                        android:layout_margin="1dp"/>
                    <View
                        android:layout_width="15dp"
                        android:layout_height="15dp"
                        android:layout_row="0"
                        android:layout_column="1"
                        android:background="#51ffff"
                        android:layout_margin="1dp"/>
                    <View
                        android:layout_width="15dp"
                        android:layout_height="15dp"
                        android:layout_row="0"
                        android:layout_column="2"
                        android:background="#51ffff"
                        android:layout_margin="1dp"/>
    // rest of rows and cols not shown.
     </GridLayout>
```

I would like to attach an `ImageView` to span across 3x3 cell

```
   gridLayout_mazeLayout = (GridLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.gridLayout_mazeLayout);
   ImageView imageView_robot = new ImageView(rootView.getContext());
   imageView_robot.setBackgroundResource(R.mipmap.imageacross3x3);

    GridLayout.Spec row = GridLayout.spec(0);
    GridLayout.Spec col = GridLayout.spec(0);
    GridLayout.LayoutParams gridLayoutParam = new GridLayout.LayoutParams(row, col);
    gridLayout_mazeLayout.addView(imageView_robot,gridLayoutParam);
```

But doing so seems to introduce a new space for the `ImagineView`. What I want to achieve is to attach the `ImagineView` on top of the cell, instead of adding it to the `GridLayout`.

Answer (score 0):

Change `<View`> inside `<GridLayout>` to `<ImageView>` with unique Id and then you can get instance in your Java code using `findViewById()` or if you want to build it dynamically just remove `<View>` from `<GridLayout>` tag and use `addView()` to insert `ImageView` into `GridLayout`.